# How to find how successful an iPhone app is?

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes

Like for websites we have Alexa.com which show site analytics of the site and its rankings, etc.

Is there something similar for iPhone Apps?

Basically I want to know how successful an App is. I know we can guage it by seeing number of user reviews but at times there are not enough reviews and it becomes difficult to guage the success of that app.

Comment: How is this programming related? I see nothing about objective-c, cocoa-touch, or iphone-sdk-4.0.

Comment: I know it may not be programming related, but I am not sure which Stackoverflow site it would go in? Superuser? Apple? and under which tags? Can you please suggest? Thanks!

Comment: think it belongs on programmers.stackexchange

Comment: Is this for your own app or someone else app?

Comment: You can't get data of others apps.

Comment: You can't get actual download numbers but the sites mentioned below can give you store ranking history for any app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use [appannie.com](http://appannie.com) for our tracking... it's quite good.

Comment: Appannie.com has, under Store Stats, features similar to Alexa like Rankings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

All the datas are on your iTunesConnect account. However those datas are not always very clear. If you want nice charts, aggregation of reviews and rankings and several other stats about your applications, there are a lot of softwares that aggregates those datas.

I am using [Prismo](http://prismoapp.com/) for instance, but there are several other applications that do the same thing (even web apps).

Answer (score 1):

[Localytics](http://www.localytics.com/) is good..